# Print message to spring shell while the shell is starting up

Tags: java, maven, spring-shell, appassembler

I'm using spring shell and I want to add some "loading.." message so when the user open the shell the message will shown immediately (on the shell).

My idea is to add "ECHO loading" command to the batch file but I can't figure out how can I add some print command to the batch file that is created using 
*appassembler-maven-plugin*. There is a way to add this ECHO to the batch file from the pom?

This is the plugin I use to create the batch file in pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
                <assembleDirectory>target/lang</assembleDirectory>
                <useWildcardClassPath>true</useWildcardClassPath>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>org.springframework.shell.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                        <id>cs</id>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Is there a way to add the ECHO command to the batch file permanently?
Or, if that does not work, is there a way to print message to the shell that will appear between the time the shell is opening to the time the shell actually ready for use?

Comment: I am not understanding how this code has anything to do with Windows Batch Files. Seems like the batch-file does not apply to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that batch file is the way to go.
I would try doing it be creating a method that calls Bootstrap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Your message");
        logger.info("Or mybe this way if you set the logger to print to console");
        Bootstrap.main(args);
    }
```